# Active resource error "ArgumentError at expected an attributes Hash, got "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activeresource

I have configured my rails app to consume Redmine api using Active resource. 
In my model redmine.rb, i put the following code

```
require 'active_resource'  

class Redmine < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:9000/"
  self.format = :json  
  self.element_name = "issues"
  self.user = "admin"
  self.password = "admin"
end
```

And in my controller

```
def index
  @data = Redmine.find(:all)
end
```

But its showing argument error ArgumentError at expected an attributes Hash, got
and showing the json data with this error.

How to get out of this error, I am using

```
gem 'activeresource', :require => 'active_resource'
```

But when i am using XML parsing its showing no error, then i think problem is in json parsing. please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that it works with XML. I have the same error with json.

Comment: I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375389/active-resource-complaining-about-expects-an-hash to get this working with json.